# Gmail automatically urlencodes links in mail

Tags: angularjs, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email to a gmail account containing a link which looks like this:

> http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1

This is a link to an AngularJS application which needs the second '#' as a separator.
The problem is that gmail changes the seconds '#' to '%23' and this causes the application not to recognize the char as a separator.
Is there anything I can do with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" ? for the email?

Comment: It's already set this way..

Comment: Same problem here, though I see urldecode on the link, not urlencode. I use it for password reset and registration links with base64 encode, but they arrive malformed because google does an urldecode on them, so users cannot login with them. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test using gmail to try to figure out what happens.

Here is the raw message

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.96.50.232 with HTTP; Mon, 19 Jan 2015 05:44:30 -0800 (PST)
Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:44:30 +0100
Delivered-To: *******@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CPZt8dX3Q17wXmU7UT2iXp7q4tSn1UsDmyiUbXFVK7xE2Q0C10A@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: <name> <*******@gmail.com>
To: <name> <*******@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf303b41179134a6050d0185f4

--20cf303b41179134a6050d0185f4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1

--20cf303b41179134a6050d0185f4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1">http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1</a><br></div>

--20cf303b41179134a6050d0185f4--
```

The original message is showing the correct values, but I also noticed how my actual gmail client shows the second # as the html encoded %23.

Surprisingly enough, in contrast to what I suggested in my comment, using plain-text will actually give the desired result.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.96.50.232 with HTTP; Mon, 19 Jan 2015 06:06:39 -0800 (PST)
Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2015 15:06:39 +0100
Delivered-To: *****@gmail.com
Message-ID: <KMBt8bX2CrmEL66iRFAJ+_s_1W2eodD=9X=bMdsBK_13qzh6DaA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test4
From: <name> <*****@gmail.com>
To: <name> <*****@gmail.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1
```

I don't know how your AngularJS application reads the link from the email, so plain-text may not be an option, but the link in the above email is mapped to `http://www.example.com/#/something#param=1` in my gmail client.

Comment: Thank you @Scherling, but wouldn't this content type prevent me from sending HTML in mt message?

Comment: @EphiGabay As I said, it really comes down to how the AngularJS application process the data in the email. There's no real need for it to be html encoded if all you need is an url. As far as I know, there's nothing you can do to prevent gmail from translating the original email to an encoded format, which breaks your link. So if plain-text won't do the trick, the only solution I see, is to fix it in the Angular application that recieves the message.

Comment: I do need to send html in the email and not just the link, so encoding the email as text/plain wouldn't help me. Thank you very much for your help anyway :)